# I can't see five icons rendering in the footer using native base?

Tags: javascript, react-native, icons, footer, native-base

Hey guys I am trying to get five icon in the footer of the screen using native base but I can only see three icon can any body help me out what is the issue? I am referring to [this link](http://nativebase.io/docs/v0.2.0/components).
Here is the code.

```
<Container>
    <Footer>
        <Button transparent>
            <Icon size={30} color={'#fff'} name={'ios-telephone'} />
        </Button>
        <Button transparent>
            <Icon size={25} color={'#fff'} name={'ios-cycle'}/>
        </Button>
        <Button transparent>
            <Icon size={25} color={'#fff'} name={'ios-home'}/>
        </Button>
        <Button transparent>
            <Icon size={25} color={'#fff'} name={'ios-menu'}/>
        </Button>
        <Button transparent>
            <Icon size={25} color={'#fff'} name={'chatbox'}/>
        </Button>
    </Footer>
</Container>
```

Can any body help me out what is the issue? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring old version of NSP
Check the latest [docs](http://strapmobile.com/docs/native-starter-pro/v4.0.0/components#footer) for same